# When would you use apt-get remove over apt-get autoremove?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

I understand that `apt-get remove` removes packages and `apt-get autoremove` is to remove any packages that were installed to fulfil a dependency for a given package. So for example if I installed LibreOffice and it had dependencies on say Java and installed it as part of the installation when I run the command `apt-get libreoffice`, why would I run the command `apt-get remove libreoffice` followed by `apt-get autoremove`? Am I not able to simply run the command `apt-get autoremove libreoffice`? Or is the combination of `apt-get remove` and `apt-get autoremove` for a different purpose?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on how much you trust the dependancy tracker. While almost always correct, there are times when you would want a dependancy to remain, particularly when you are a developer or power user installing software that is not in the repository.

If you always install software through apt-get, without exception, and trust all the dependancies to be correct (which they usually are), then you can use **`apt-get autoremove`** and gain a small amount of drive space and a reduced exposure to potential security holes by having it remove packages that no longer have any packages that need them.

But if you install software manually, or develop software, or do not want to deal with a possible dependancy error, then not using autoremove to clear potentially unused packages is probably the safer choice. Regardless of whether you use `apt-get autoremove` every now and then or not, you will always remove software using **`apt-get remove Package`**

For example, if I install `AwesomePackage`, it may depend on `AwesomeLibrary`, and thus `AwesomeLibrary` will get automatically installed as a **dependancy**. When I remove `AwesomePackage` using autoremove, as long as no other package has `AwesomeLibrary` as a dependancy it will be uninstalled as well. But if `SuperPackage` also requires `AwesomeLibrary`, or if I had installed `AwesomeLibrary` explicitly myself rather than having it come in automatically as a dependancy (`apt-get install AwesomeLibrary`), then autoremove would not get rid of it.

The reason it is not the default is that having `AwesomeLibrary` on the system, unused, is a very minor issue. It will almost never cause problems, and most dependancies don't take up much space. There are exceptions, but the times when removing a dependancy will cause problems outnumber the times when it will solve or prevent a problem.

Comment: Sorry Myrddin Emrys. You lost me there. So let me try and understand what you said. So for example if I installed libreoffice using apt-get, it would install a whole bunch of dependencies assuming I didn't have them installed already. Now if I then decide to get rid of libreoffice, I assume I would run `apt-get remove libreoffice`

Comment: If I wanted the dependencies it installed to remain is that correct? If I wanted to rid myself of both libreoffice and its associated dependencies assuming there were not used by another program, I take it I would run the command `apt-get autoremovelibreoffice`? Is that correct?

Comment: That is absolutely correct @PeanutsMonkey. Autoremove will also remove **other packages** that the named package depended on, if they are no longer required by anything and were not installed separately on purpose.

Comment: Actually, that is not absolutely correct; I had some incorrect syntax in my answer (as @cooper pointed out). I have corrected this in the answer above. `apt-get autoremove` is a separate command from `apt-get remove Package`, I apologize for the initial misinformation.

Comment: Thanks Myrddin Emrys. Sorry if I am being a n00b. When you say that `There are exceptions, but the times when removing a dependancy will cause problems outnumber the times when it will solve or prevent a problem`. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If the dependency tracking is wrong, `autoremove` might eliminate a library or other dependancy that was needed, even though it's not supposed to. If you have a couple applications that are installed manually, they may have dependancies that are untracked. These situations are more likely to occur than situations where the space taken up by an unused dependancy causes a problem, or where a security hole in an unused dependancy causes a problem. Thus, cleaning unused dependancies is more likely to cause problems than not. It's not a bad thing; it's just good to be aware of the possible issues.

Answer (score 12):

You can find the description of **remove**, **autoremove**, **purge**, **clean** and **autoclean**, as well as the syntax in the manpages for apt-get: `man apt-get`.

If you are still unsure after reading it though (I was) the best way to clarify it is to try it out.

Below is an example of a full dependency tree for *vim*:

[image: vim-dependency-tree]

You can get it with:

```
apt-rdepends -d vim > vim.dot
dotty vim.dot
```

You can also get a list of the immediate dependencies using `apt-cache depends` (see [Declaring relationships between packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html) for more info):

```
$ apt-cache depends vim
vim
  Depends: vim-common
  Depends: vim-runtime
  Depends: libacl1
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgpm2
  Depends: libselinux1
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Suggests: <ctags>
    exuberant-ctags
  Suggests: vim-doc
  Suggests: vim-scripts
```

So it looks like *vim* depends on a number of packages, let's attempt to install it with `apt-get install` and see what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim
...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  vim-common vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-common vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 25.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

In order to get *vim* to work we need *vim-common* and *vim-runtime* packages and `apt-get` will take care of it. We can verify it with `dpkg -s pkg...` (see `man dpkg` for more info on statuses):

```
$ sudo dpkg -s libc6
Package: libc6
Status: install ok installed        // we already have it, no need to install

$ sudo dpkg -s vim-common
Package: vim-common
Status: deinstall ok config-files   // we don't have it, have to install
```

Just as we checked what *vim* depends on, we can also check what other things depend on the same packages as *vim* using `apt-cache rdepends`. We should see *vim* among (possibly) other things:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends vim-common
vim-common
Reverse Depends:
  vim-latexsuite
  vim-addon-manager
  vim-tiny
  vim-nox
  vim-gtk
  vim-gnome
 |vim-dbg
  vim-athena
  vim                               // there it is
```

Let's continue with the installation. Once we have installed *vim* we can experience the difference between **remove** and **autoremove**. Let's attempt to **remove** first:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove vim
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  vim
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,922 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

`apt-get remove` would then remove *vim* but ***not its dependencies leaving them behind***. Let's now try to remove one of the *vim*'s dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove vim-runtime
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 24.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

This would remove the dependency *vim-runtime* ***as well as the package that depends on it***, namely *vim*. Out of curiosity, let's see what would happen if we removed a dependency that is lower on *vim*'s dependency tree:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libgpm2
...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkglext1 libqtassistantclient4 libtiff-tools libtiff5 python-qt4
  python-sip python-sqlalchemy python-sqlalchemy-ext
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  anki cheese gimp gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry gnome-control-center      // !
  gnome-media gnome-video-effects gstreamer0.10-plugins-good libaa1         // !
  libcheese-gtk21 libcheese3 libgpm2 mplayer quodlibet vim vlc w3m          // !
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 18 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 63.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

It would remove vim and lots of goodies!

Let's proceed with `apt-get remove vim` then. Once we have done it we should have some leftovers. If we now try **autoremove** we can see:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  vim-common vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 23.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

These are the two packages `apt-get remove` left behind even though nothing else needed them.

Experimented with apt-get 0.9.7.9.

Answer (score 4):

According to this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=996053 autoremove will remove all packages that other programs do not need.  You would do 'apt-get autoremove', not 'apt-get autoremove libreoffice'.  Also removing unneeded packages does not just free up a little disk space, it reduces the 'attack surface' of your system.

Comment: I can see that unused libraries can be an attack vector, but it seems to be a very minor issue to me, relative to the significant pain of improper removal (which I've seen happen more than once). Thank you for the info about usage however... I have actually been describing autoremove improperly (I don't use it myself, so didn't realize), thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

`remove` will delete the specified program whereas `autoremove` will include dependencies otherwise not used anymore.

Also, If you'd like to free up drive space, a useful and safe command is...

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

That removes the aptitude cache in /var/cache/apt/archives

Comment: Sorry for being such a n00b but I don't quite follow that. So if I run the command `apt-get remove libreoffice`, I take it that it'll simply remove libreoffice. Is that right? However if I run the command `apt-get autoremove libreoffice`, that would not only remove libreoffice but also its dependencies?

Comment: That's correct. So let's say that I install `neverball` and `neverball` depends on a package called `libisfun`. If I `apt-get remove neverball` then it will remove just the `neverball` package. If I `apt-get autoremove neverball` then it will remove `neverball` and `libisfun` if `libisfun` is not a dependent on any other application.